# NdkMediaCodec returns ERROR(0x90000012)

Tags: java, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

I am working on turning my java decode process to JNI.
First, I'm using the following source code to initial the mediacodec:

```
AMediaCodec* codec;
AMediaFormat* format = AMediaFormat_new();
AMediaFormat_setInt32(format,AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_WIDTH,1920);
AMediaFormat_setInt32(format,AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_HEIGHT,1080);
AMediaFormat_setString(format,AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME,"video/avc");

codec = AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType(AVR_MEDIA_MIME_FORMAT);
AMediaCodec_configure(codec, format, newNativeWindow, NULL, 0);
AMediaCodec_start(codec);
```

and then fill the buffer with.(the data is ok in java)

```
buffer = AMediaCodec_getOutputBuffer(codec, buffer_index, &buffer_size);
if(buffer >=0){
    memcpy(buffer, background, background_size);
    AMediaCodec_queueInputBuffer(codec,buffer_index, 0, background_size, 0, 0);
}
```

But It doesn't work. the log is:

```
I/ACodec(19130):  [] Now uninitialized
I/OMXClient(19130): Using client-side OMX mux.
I/ACodec(19130): can't find wfdsink-exynos-enable
I/ACodec(19130): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] configureOutputBuffersFromNativeWindow setBufferCount : 6, minUndequeuedBuffers : 4
I/ACodec(19130): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] allocated meta buffer with ID 0xed110060 (pointer = 0xf49e5000)
I/ACodec(19130): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] allocated meta buffer with ID 0xed110510 (pointer = 0xf49e5020)
I/ACodec(19130): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] allocated meta buffer with ID 0xecf06970 (pointer = 0xf49e5040)
I/ACodec(19130): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] allocated meta buffer with ID 0xed406290 (pointer = 0xf49e5060)
I/ACodec(19130): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] allocated meta buffer with ID 0xed1106f0 (pointer = 0xf49e5080)
I/ACodec(19130): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] allocated meta buffer with ID 0xed406100 (pointer = 0xf49e50a0)
I/ACodec(19130): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Executing
I/Timeline(19130): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@298cf478 time:6236268
E/ACodec(19130): [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] ERROR(0x90000012)
E/ACodec(19130): signalError(omxError 0x90000012, internalError -2147483648)
E/MediaCodec(19130): Codec reported err 0x90000012, actionCode 0, while in state 6
E/NdkMediaCodec(19130): sf error code: -38
E/NdkMediaCodec(19130): sf error code: -38
E/NdkMediaCodec(19130): sf error code: -38
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two potential problems in your code:

1. the condition "if(buffer >=0)" is not correct, should be "if(buffer)"
2. be sure background_size <= buffer_size